# Luggage storage in Garmisch-Partenkirchen

Tags: germany, luggage-storage, bavaria

I am planning to visit Garmisch-Partenkirchen (GAP) on a day trip this December. If possible, I would like to leave Munich in the morning, spend the day in GAP and continue to Innsbruck in the afternoon. However, to do this I would need to leave my luggage (two mid-sized briefcases) somewhere.

If I cannot leave my luggage in GAP, I would have to leave it in Munich and I would like to avoid travelling back. Is it possible to leave luggage somewhere in GAP?

Comment: I am a little bit confused: you call Garmisch-Partenkirchen a day trip but you also talk about a hotel there … You also mention checking out from Munich and then going to Innsbruck. Do I understand you correctly that your trip involves you leaving Munich for Innsbruck and that you plan to spend your travel day in GAP? (Also, as a local it is highly unusual for me to see the abbreviation GP; everyone I know abbreviates it GAP ;) .)

Comment: @Jan: this will be my first time in Germany so please excuse the unusual abbreviation. I will be checking-out of Munich only if I get to put my luggage somewhere in GAP. Otherwise I would have come back to Munich and then next morning travelled to Innsbruck (or Venice...still deciding on that). Based on answer below now I can leave Munich with luggage.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are lockers at the train station in Garmisch-Partenkirchen, as mentioned here: https://www.bahnhof.de/bahnhof-en/Garmisch-Partenkirchen-3805998
There are no prices on that page, but usually a small locker (hand luggage size) costs 3 - 4 Euros per day, and a big locker for a checked-in luggage size is around 5 - 6 Euros per day. However, as soon as you open it, you have to pay again, so you need to take everything with you that you need during the day.

Comment: I also believe that the lockers take coins (1 euro or 2 euros, iirc) only. Should be the same brand as in all German stations that have lockers.

Comment: I have already seen a newer version of those lockers, which also take cards, but that was only in some of the bigger cities, so most likely for GP it's coins only, as you mentioned.

Comment: thanks Jan and dunni for this additional info. I'll make sure to carry coins.

Comment: @Dayne If you are from the US, you'll need quite a bit more cash (coins and notes) in Germany than you are used to.  You can probably pay for an evening meal in a posh restaurant by card, and almost certainly a hotel, but not a light lunch, and certainly not a sandwich in the bakers.  (I was surprised that one of our favourite restaurants didn't take credit cards, only e-cash debit cards.)

Comment: @MartinBonner: thanks for this. I will plan to carry sufficient cash.